# Prove that $2^{-n} \leq \max_{x \in [-1,1]} |w(x)|$, where $w(x) := \prod_{j=0}^n (x - x_j)$

Tags: real-analysis

Given nodes $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $w(x) := \prod_{j=0}^n (x - x_j)$ I need to show that $$2^{-n} \leq \max_{x \in [-1,1]} |w(x)|$$

and where equality is reached for the roots of the n+1-th Chebycheff polynomial: $T_{n+1} = \cos((n+1)\arccos(x)), x \in [-1,1]$

As a hint I'm given the function $q(x) = 2^{-n}T_{n+1}(x) - w(x)$

I have been sitting on this for some time without making any progress at all. The max over the interval throws me off, I'm not sure how to generally find the max given some nodes, only for the cases with 2 and 3 nodes I was able to determine a rule for finding the max. I'm not sure whether it's even necessary to know how to determine the max to lower bound the expression though.
I also don't know how the hint could be helpful.

Can anybody please provide some more hints?